# Python: How to get stock data for free (for many tickers, like S&P 500)

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance, stock, stockquotes

I want to get stock data in Python for some analysis.

And I want to do analysis on many stocks, not a single one like AAPL, but like S&P 500. Specifically, US stock end-of-day price and other info like adjusted price, sector etc.

How can I do it?

---

I'm sorry if this question is a bit too simple. I tried to find data but didn't have a good solution.

I tried `quandl`, but seems only support fetch data by ticker, and so is `Yahoo finance` (from https://www.quora.com/Using-Python-whats-the-best-way-to-get-stock-data). One possible source is `Quantopian`, but it only supports analysis in their online notebook. Now I'm trying `Alph Advantage`

When I see other's project, it's just about a csv. Did I miss something in quandl or Yahoo Finance? Or Do I need to manually fetch every ticker of SP 500 from them?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use yahoo finance for real time data like for nearly all quotes:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb

ticker='BTC-USD'

ticker=wb.DataReader(ticker,start='2015-1-1',data_source='yahoo')
print(ticker)
```

Yahoo Finance will give you hihg-low-adj_close etc.
Just look up for the quote name from yahoo finance page and you will get all the data